# How to fit a curve to a histogram

Tags: r, histogram, curve-fitting, kernel-density, density-plot

I've explored similar questions asked about this topic but I am having some trouble producing a nice curve on my histogram. I understand that some people may see this as a duplicate but I haven't found anything currently to help solve my problem.

Although the data isn't visible here, here is some variables I am using just so you can see what they represent in the code below.

```
Differences <- subset(Score_Differences, select = Difference, drop = T)
m = mean(Differences)
std = sqrt(var(Differences))
```

Here is the very first curve I produce (the code seems most common and easy to produce but the curve itself doesn't fit that well).

```
hist(Differences, density = 15, breaks = 15, probability = TRUE, xlab = "Score Differences", ylim = c(0,.1), main = "Normal Curve for Score Differences")
curve(dnorm(x,m,std),col = "Red", lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

I really like this but don't like the curve going into the negative region.

```
hist(Differences, probability = TRUE)
lines(density(Differences), col = "Red", lwd = 2)
lines(density(Differences, adjust = 2), lwd = 2, col = "Blue")
```

[image]

This is the same histogram as the first, but with frequencies. Still doesn't look that nice.

```
h = hist(Differences, density = 15, breaks = 15, xlab = "Score Differences", main = "Normal Curve for Score Differences")
xfit = seq(min(Differences),max(Differences))
yfit = dnorm(xfit,m,std)
yfit = yfit*diff(h$mids[1:2])*length(Differences)
lines(xfit, yfit, col = "Red", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Another attempt but no luck. Maybe because I am using `qnorm`, when the data obviously isn't normal. The curve goes into the negative direction again.

```
sample_x = seq(qnorm(.001, m, std), qnorm(.999, m, std), length.out = l)
binwidth = 3
breaks = seq(floor(min(Differences)), ceiling(max(Differences)), binwidth)
hist(Differences, breaks)
lines(sample_x, l*dnorm(sample_x, m, std)*binwidth, col = "Red")
```

[image]

**The only curve that visually looks nice is the 2nd, but the curve falls into the negative direction.**

My question is **"Is there a "standard way" to place a curve on a histogram?"** This data certainly isn't normal. 3 of the procedures I presented here are from similar posts but I am having some troubles obviously. I feel like all methods of fitting a curve will depend on the data you're working with.

---

**Update with solution**

Thanks to Zheyuan Li and others! I will leave this up for my own reference and hopefully others as well.

```
hist(Differences, probability = TRUE)
lines(density(Differences, cut = 0), col = "Red", lwd = 2)
lines(density(Differences, adjust = 2, cut = 0), lwd = 2, col = "Blue")
```

[image]

Comment: In scenarios where I don't know the distribution ahead of time (ie, all empirical scenarios), I use a kernel density (sometimes without histogram). If your goal is to see how well the data matches a particular distribution, then you could graph the kernel density together with the known distribution.

Comment: @lmo I like that idea. It seems like my kernel goes off the histogram into the negative direction though. Its bothersome, but oh well..  Thank you both.

Comment: This is really a statistical question. There are many ways of approaching estimation of densities, but doing so in a principled manner requires sitting down with a statittician and discussing hte scientific background for the investiagation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so you are just struggling with the fact that `density` goes beyond "natural range". Well, just set `cut = 0`. You possibly want to read [`plot.density` extends “xlim” beyond the range of my data. Why and how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39554039/4891738) for why. In that answer, I was using `from` and `to`. But now I am using `cut`.

```
## consider a mixture, that does not follow any parametric distribution family
## note, by construction, this is a strictly positive random variable
set.seed(0)
x <- rbeta(1000, 3, 5) + rexp(1000, 0.5)

## (kernel) density estimation offers a flexible nonparametric approach
d <- density(x, cut = 0)

## you can plot histogram and density on the density scale
hist(x, prob = TRUE, breaks = 50)
lines(d, col = 2)
```

[image]

**Note, by `cut = 0`, density estimation is done strictly within `range(x)`. Outside this range, density is 0.**

Comment: Ahhh! I see now. Wow that is convenient. For the most part it seems like I was going about it properly. Thanks for the clarification and patience. Greatly appreciated.